# Give an example of a linear map $T$ such that $\dim(\operatorname{null}T) = 3$ and $\dim(\operatorname{range}T) = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Can I get a verification if this is the right way to approach this problem?

> Give an example of a linear map $T$ such that $\dim(\operatorname{null}T) = 3$ and $\dim(\operatorname{range}T) = 2$.

By the fundamental theorem of linear maps, 
$$\dim V = \dim \operatorname{range}T + \dim\operatorname{null}T,$$
thus $\dim V=5$. Let $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^5$.
Let $f_1,f_2$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define a linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $$T(a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3+a_4e_4+a_5e_5)=a_1f_1+a_2f_2.$$

Thus $\dim(\operatorname{null}T) = 3$ and $\dim(\operatorname{range}T) = 2$.

Comment: Note that $imT=span(T(e_1).,,,,,T(e_n))$ where $e_i$ is a basis vector.

Comment: What you've done seems like the most straightforward way to answer the question as it is phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example is correct (though like the other answerer, I would tend to prefer something more specific).

Based on your previous post and your use of the word "thus", I assume that you're also trying to prove that the range and nullspace have the dimension you claim (even though such a step is typically considered unnecessary).  I would say that you have *not* done so in the answer you have presented. One proof would be as follows:

> We see that the range is given by $\{a_1 f_1 + a_2 f_2 : a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb R\}$.  This is the span of the linearly independent set $\{f_1,f_2\}$.  Thus, the dimension of the range is $2$.
>
> On the other hand, we note that
> $$
> T(a_1e_1+a_2e_2+a_3e_3+a_4e_4+a_5e_5) = 0 \iff\\
> a_1f_1+a_2f_2 = 0 \iff\\
> a_1 = 0\text{ and } a_2 = 0.
> $$
> Thus, the kernel of $T$ is given by $\{0e_1 + 0e_2 + a_3e_3+a_4e_4+a_5e_5 : a_3,a_4,a_5 \in \Bbb R\}$.  This is the span of the linearly independent set $\{e_3,e_4,e_5\}$.  Thus, the dimension of the kernel is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do an easy variation on your example,  where $V=\Bbb R^5$ and $W=\Bbb R^2$.

Define $T$ by $T(x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)=(x_1,x_3)$..

Then clearly $T$ is surjective.   Hence $\operatorname {rank}T=2$.  This forces, by the "Fundamental theorem", as you call it, that $\operatorname {null}T=3$.

It is easy to come up with other such variations.   Here are some others, in a slightly different spirit:   $T(v_1,v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)=(av_1+bv_2, cv_3)$, for any $a,b, c\ne0$  Actually, 
we could let one of $a$ and $b$ be zero.

Actually,  the collection of all such maps is in $1-1$ correspondence with the set of rank $2, 2×5$ matrices.

I think your approach was fine, and by coincidence,  I defined the same map, essentially,  without having read what you did carefully yet.  Though I used, implicitly,  the standard basis,  and you, as @Arthur pointed out,  did it in a more general setting.

Answer (score 1):

I was also attempting to solve this question but your approach seemed abstract to me, and upon little reflection, I was able to come up with the following more concrete example which helped increase my understanding of the concept.

The key understanding I got, which prompted me to write this answer, is as follows : since any linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^2)$, which has dim range $T = 2$ will definitely have dim null $T = 3$ (according to Fundamental theorem of Linear Maps), all we need to do is to look for a map $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^2)$ for which dim range $T = 2$.

Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^2)$ by :
$$T(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (x_1 + x_2 +x_3 +x_4+x_5, x_1 + x_2)$$

The range has a basis $(1, 0),(0,1)$ and hence dim range $T = 2$ and null $T$ has basis $(1, -1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, -1)$ and hence dim null $T =3$.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely correct. This will give a linear map with the properties you're asked for.

I think that it is a bit too general to actually be "an example". I think it would be better if you *actually pick* a concrete basis. But that's a personal aesthetic belief, and one would have to be pretty pedantic about it to say that that makes you wrong.

One objection with a bit more substance is that you haven't actually *proven* that your claims about the kernel and the image actually holds. You don't need much, but if this were on a test or an assignment and I was correcting it, I would want you to spend a sentence or two on each of them. For instance

> $\dim \operatorname{im} T=2$ because $T$ is clearly surjective and $\dim \Bbb R^2=2$. Then by the rank nullity theorem, we also get $\dim\ker T=3$.